# 20.04 takes a long time to boot from a m.2 ssd

Tags: boot, mount

Noob here, I managed to install 20.04 to an SSD, a Samsung 850 EVO 250Gb (mz-n5e250)  however, I am getting a fairly long boot time compared to a standard ssd install. 
First of all, noticed that during install it detected the m.2 as /dev/sdd instead of /dev/nvme...probably nothing, installation proceeded without issue.
Now this is dual boot setup alongside Windows 10. Grub works fine and then it's a long wait...When I get to Ubuntu desktop I notice that in favourites I can see that root, efi and home are mounted as media, I haven't seen this before. Anyway, digging deeper the culprit appears to be udisks2:

sudo systemd-analyze blame:

```
32.803s udisks2.service                                                                          
 6.452s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
 5.296s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
  563ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
  559ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount                                                   
  558ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                                  
  557ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-27.mount
```

and critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @34.045s
└─udisks2.service @1.241s +32.803s
  └─basic.target @1.189s
    └─sockets.target @1.189s
      └─snapd.socket @1.188s +478us
        └─sysinit.target @1.185s
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @894ms +290ms
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @867ms +25ms
              └─local-fs.target @863ms
                └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @22.329s
                  └─run-user-1000.mount @22.182s
                    └─swap.target @815ms
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3f951984\x2d35cf\x2d4e0d\x2d8dee\x2d072d2f4c8d66.swap @767ms +47ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3f951984\x2d35cf\x2d4e0d\x2d8dee\x2d072d2f4c8d66.device @759ms
```

So, I checked fstab thinking something might be amiss:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdd1 during installation
UUID=2ac96265-f633-42a7-8ab4-5f3f4a9065ec /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6AE9-5D89  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdd3 during installation
UUID=8e1a5a66-e062-42cd-bf93-2042e61dd9ba /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdd2 during installation
UUID=3f951984-35cf-4e0d-8dee-072d2f4c8d66 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

compared it to blkid:

```
/dev/sdd2: UUID="3f951984-35cf-4e0d-8dee-072d2f4c8d66" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="90c89aee-5a06-4d7b-b292-45ea9a1bf90b"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="2ac96265-f633-42a7-8ab4-5f3f4a9065ec" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6a78d7fe-ebdf-44c4-9839-58bd1d3435a2"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="0294E89394E88A8D" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="166342dd-a166-4598-b639-ac44b12e1ffe"
/dev/sda2: UUID="6AE9-5D89" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="9218c53d-42bd-4ca3-b222-e6fa7d52378f"
/dev/sda4: UUID="84C2F292C2F28826" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5889556a-909f-4410-a177-30cb5b843280"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="Data" UUID="ACF4143FF4140DE8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="981bc30b-aedb-4269-814b-b768667d4dde"
/dev/sdd3: UUID="8e1a5a66-e062-42cd-bf93-2042e61dd9ba" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ff33cea9-5f9a-476a-b2b4-a3d2da50e67e"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="b488c487-f54f-4f7f-a144-18e91e01efbc"
/dev/sdc1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="1b884629-3787-4cab-a008-1f3de408c226"
```

So, everything looks okay (as far as I can tell).

I ran 'sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i udisks2':

```
May  7 10:56:51 ollie-MS-7B87 dbus-daemon[1103]: [session uid=125 pid=1103] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=125 pid=1097 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
May  7 10:56:51 ollie-MS-7B87 dbus-daemon[900]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UDisks2' unit='udisks2.service' requested by ':1.27' (uid=125 pid=1119 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor " label="unconfined")
May  7 10:57:11 ollie-MS-7B87 dbus-daemon[1472]: [session uid=1000 pid=1472] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=1000 pid=1467 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1517]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1119]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 dbus-daemon[1472]: [session uid=1000 pid=1472] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 dbus-daemon[1103]: [session uid=125 pid=1103] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1517]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1517]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1119]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 tracker-miner-f[1467]: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 gvfs-udisks2-vo[1119]: monitor says it's not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 tracker-extract[1096]: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 tracker-extract[1466]: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported
May  7 10:57:16 ollie-MS-7B87 tracker-miner-f[1097]: remote volume monitor with dbus name org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor is not supported
May  7 10:57:23 ollie-MS-7B87 udisksd[942]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.UDisks2 on the system message bus
```

I can confirm that issue is not confined to the m.2 but also an external ssd on a fresh install. udisks2 is freaking out again mounting /efi , /root and /home as media in the favourites bar. Guessing there is something in my system setup that Ubuntu doesn't particularly like.

Comment: What's the make and model of the M.2 drive?

Comment: Hi, it is a Samsung 850 EVO 250Gb (mz-n5e250)

Comment: I've tried disabling udisks2 during startup using 'systemctl disable udisks2.service', but udisks2 seems to ignore this! Is the dbus daemon usurping this by placing it's own call?

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! It *was* something in the system that was throwing off udisks2, it was the DVD/CD-ROM Drive! I have a Samsung Tru-Direct WriteMaster and as soon as it was disconnected from SATA the next boot was perfect. Along with 'normal' boot times the automount feature of udisks2 is also working, as is gone the erroneous mounting of system partitions such as /efi and /root in the favourites bar.