# Automount USB drive broken

Tags: automount

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS suddenly stopped mounting my USB hard drive when I plug it in. I can manually mount it. This drive mounts on Windows 10 (2 different PCs) and Debian with zero problem - so clearly the drive is ok.
One thing that seemed to happen at the same time is the appearance of two nondescript icons on the sidebar. One is the FileSystem Root and the other is labelled efi (this is my Windows 10 drive). Not sure if this was coincidence.

While looking for gvfs errors in syslog:

May 12 07:04:00 roger gvfs-udisks2-vo[1701]: monitor says it's not supported.

Searching on internet found that the culprit is the dvd drive.

[20.04 takes a long time to boot from a m.2 ssd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236417/20-04-takes-a-long-time-to-boot-from-a-m-2-ssd)

If I boot with the dvd disconnected, all is back to normal and Ubuntu boots faster.

Thanks for the hints.

Comment: EFI is EFI, not your Windows 10 drive. And something is wrong indeed if it appears as user accessible.

Comment: The question should include your syslog output from mounting and unmounting, and fsck output to *really* show that "*the drive is  ok*" While checking your log, look for gvfs errors, too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not so clear that the drive is OK. Linux will not mount, or mount read only, if a volume is not clean. Before attempting anything else, have the drive connected to Windows, run the Windows drive checking tool, and then properly disconnect from Windows (using the eject icon in the tray). Next time you connect to Ubuntu, the drive will mount properly.